# unable to map color onto a network graph from an additional variable using ggraph

Tags: r, nlp, visualization, ggraph

I am attempting to create a text network graph. I am working with pivoted survey data, and attempting to associate words from open-ended comments with associated numeric responses. I've constructed word correlations and graphed them, but am having a devil of a time associating numeric values back into the network graph. I have experience with R, but I've not had formal training/classes and I feel confident I'm missing something pretty basic right now.

I was able to successfully create a plot using the following code, assuming graph is my data frame, containing variables x (raw numeric score from the survey data), row_number (to tie individual word used back to its initial open ended comment), word, n (# of times "word" appears in the dataset), and y (average of x per word).

```
graph %>%
  group_by(word) %>%
  filter(n() >= 1000)%>%
  pairwise_cor(word, row_number, upper=FALSE) %>%
  filter(correlation > .09) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame() %>%
  ggraph(layout = "fr") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(edge_alpha = correlation), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_node_point(color = "lightblue", size = 5) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE) +
  theme_void()
```

The pairwise_cor function essentially reshapes the dataframe into item1, item2, and correlation, dropping all other variables, meaning my relevant color-assigning variables were dropped, so I created a correlated words dataset, and then a final_df that joins individual word average scores (y) with the correlated_words dataset:

```
final <- cor_df %>%
  left_join(filt_df, by = join_by(item1 == word)) %>%
  left_join(filt_df, by = join_by(item2 == word))
```

"final" now contains item1 (word 1), item2 (word 2), correlation, n.1, y.1, n.2, and y.2 (where n is count of words and y is a weird stat: the average of X, the original survey numeric score associated that that word).

With the "final" data frame, I've now attempted a multitude of ways to map either y.1 or y.2 to the color of the nodes, generally something like:

```
as_tbl_graph(final)
ggraph(final, layout = "fr") +
 geom_node_point(aes(color = y.1), size = 5) +
 geom_node_text(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE) +
 scale_color_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
 theme_void()
```

This is the error I receive:

Error in `geom_node_point()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'y.1' not found

Not sure exactly where I'm going wrong, although I have been poring through the documentation for ggraph and tidygraph. I don't have a full conceptual understanding of the various layout possibilities, which I feel is likely where my issues lie (or possibly my confusion starts in the construction of the dataframe itself via as_tbl_graph?), and would really welcome any additional resources or documentation towards understanding those algorithms/customizing layouts. (I've read https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggraph/vignettes/Layouts.html and all of the ggraph vignettes!)

My question, boiled down, is: how can I use a numeric variable to add a color dimension to nodes in a network graph using ggraph (or more specifically, what the heck am I doing wrong)? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue with your code is that you are passing the `data.frame` `final` to `ggraph()` instead of the `tbl_graph` object `as_tbl_graph(final)`.

The second issue is that, when converting to a `tbl_graph` the `y.1` and `y.2` columns you added via the `lef_join` become a columns or features of the edges data not the nodes and are thus not available to be mapped on aesthetics in `geom_node_xxx`. To fix this second issue you have to convert `cor_df` to a `tbl_graph` first, then join your `filt_df`. This way the columns are added to the nodes data.

Note: I do only one `left_join` as a second does not make sense for the nodes data. Also I renamed the column from `y` to `value` as I encountered a warning when using `y`.

Using some fake data based on the `highschool` dataset from `ggraph`:

```r
library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

set.seed(123)

# Create example data
cor_df <- highschool
names(cor_df) <- c("item1", "item2", "correlation")

filt_df <- data.frame(
  word = as.character(unique(cor_df$item1)),
  y = runif(seq(length(unique(cor_df$item1))))
) |> 
  rename(value = y)

final_graph <- as_tbl_graph(cor_df) |>
  left_join(
    filt_df,
    by = join_by(name == word)
  )

ggraph(final_graph, layout = "fr") +
  geom_node_point(aes(color = value), size = 5) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. I'm not able to convert cor_df into a tbl_graph; I receive the error:

Error in make_empty_graph(n = 0, directed = directed) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'

My cor_df is a 3-variable data frame where the first two variables are item1 and item2 and contain individual stemmed words, and correlation contains the correlation calculated between them. Can you help me understand where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, leaving that comment for posterity, but please scratch it -- I just needed to ungroup. Figured that out.